# Div stretches only in one direction

Tags: html, css, resize, breadcrumbs, flare

I created a doc page using Flare and forced breadcrumbs to stay fixed below the top nav. The page works as it is, but I want the div to stretch across the page. 
Please see current design below:

[Click to see example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRwcZ.png)

I can stretch the div to 100% if I remove the `min-width` in the child div, but it stretches only to the right, while keeping the breadcrumbs where I want. Example below:

[Click to see example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHuvK.png)

Or I can make it stretch 100% by adding `left:0;` on the parent div, but then the breadcrumbs move out of place. I can use margin-right or right to position the div to desirable areas, but div does not sync with the rest of the content when resizing browser.

Comment: Please post your code, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question

Comment: Extremely difficult to provide a solution with no code, but chances are there are padding/margins around the parent element of your breadcrumbs div that cause it to be shifted to the right on the left side. If you could post your code, I'm sure someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: I have posted the code as suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
*{ 
  padding:10px;
}
.parent {
  margin:auto;
  width:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
.breadcrums {
  background-color:blue;
}
.full-width {
  background-color: green;
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="breadcrums">breadcrums</div>
    <div class="full-width">full-width element</div>
</div>
```

The important part here being `position`, `width`, `left` and `transform` on `.full-width`.

Answer (score 0):

Applied the css " left " property if that div has "absolute" position.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. Here are the html and css:

Html:

```
<div class="crumbs_wrapper">
 <div class="MCBreadcrumbsBox" >
  <span class="MCBreadcrumbsPrefix">You are here:</span>
  <a href="" class="MCBreadcrumbsLink">B1</a>
  <span class="MCBreadcrumbsDivider"> B2 </span>
  <a  href=""class="MCBreadcrumbsLink">B3</a>...
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.crumbs_wrapper
{  
 position: fixed;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.MCBreadcrumbsBox{
padding-bottom: 5px !important;
    padding-top: 18px !important;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -12px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 104.5em;
    box-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 15px #888888;
}
```

Th tool I use is Flare, which does not have the fixed breadcrumbs feature. Breadcrumbs are automatically generated; I only changed the CSS values and added an extra div with the `.crumbs_wrapper` class. Other classes are automatically generated by the software.

If I remove the `max-width` the div only stretches to the right, and if I add `left: 0;` to the parent div, the breadcrumbs move to the left. I can bring the breadcrumbs to the position where I want using `margin`, but it does not stay fixed when the browser is resized. Also, the paddings and margin-top are used to keep the breadcrumbs below the top nav and aligned with the rest of the content.